# Adding phone number to iphone contact - but NOT replacing!

Tags: iphone

I am trying to replicate the behavior that the iphone that happens when you tap and hold on a phone number link in a text field you get a menu "create new contact" and "add to existing contact".  I have this working except for one thing.  In the "add to existing" apple implementation if there is already a home contact, it just adds another one.  It doesn't REPLACE it.  So you can have multiple home phone numbers.

In my implementation it replaces it.  So how do I do a not-destructive phone number add?

Here is my code:

```
+(void)updatePhone:(ABRecordRef)person phone:(NSString*)phone{
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =  ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);  
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, phone,  kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
```

}

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try querying for the existing phone numbers, and then adding your new one?

Something like this (code not tested):

```
+(void)updatePhone:(ABRecordRef)person phone:(NSString*)phone{
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =  ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, phone,  kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, nil);
}
```

Comment: here is my exact code.  works whether there are phone #s previously entered or not:

+(void)updatePhone:(ABRecordRef)person phone:(NSString*)phone{
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone =  ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, phone, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
    CFRelease(multiPhone);
}