# How to add information to a contact already existing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, contacts

How to add information to a contact already existing in iPhone?

I have worked with such information, but I have not figured out how to add information to existing contacts.

```
 ABUnknownPersonViewController *unknownPersonViewController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
            unknownPersonViewController.displayedPerson = (ABRecordRef)[self buildContactDetails];
            unknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:unknownPersonViewController animated:YES];
            [unknownPersonViewController release]; 


    - (ABRecordRef)buildContactDetails {
    NSLog(@"building contact details");
    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate(); 
    CFErrorRef  error = NULL;  

    // firstname


    int i ; int taille ; 
    taille = [carte.informations count];
    NSString *nom=nil ;
    NSString *adresse=nil ;
    NSString *mail=nil,*prenom=nil,*tel=nil,*societe=nil,*profession=nil; 


    for (i=0; i<taille; i++) {

        if ([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==1) {
            nom = [(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];
        }
        else  if([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==2) {
            prenom=[(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];

        }
        else if([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==3){

            tel=[(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];

        }

        else if([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==4){

            societe=[(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];
        }       
        else if([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==5) {

            adresse = [(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];

        }
        else if ([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==6){
            mail = [(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];


        }
        else if ([(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] label]==7){
            profession = [(Information*)[self.carte.informations objectAtIndex:i] content];


        }


    }




    if(nom != nil && (![nom isEqualToString:@""])){
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,nom, NULL);
    }

    if (prenom != nil && (![prenom isEqualToString:@""])) {
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, prenom, NULL);
    }

          if(mail != nil && (![mail isEqualToString:@""])){
       ABMutableMultiValueRef email = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(email, mail, CFSTR("email"), NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty, email, &error);
    CFRelease(email); 
          }




    //Phone 
     if(tel != nil && (![tel isEqualToString:@""])){
    ABMutableMultiValueRef Phone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(Phone, tel, CFSTR("Phone"), NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person,kABPersonPhoneProperty, Phone, &error);
    CFRelease(Phone); 
     }


        if(adresse != nil && (![adresse isEqualToString:@""])){
    // Start of Address
    ABMutableMultiValueRef address = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType);  
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [addressDict setObject:adresse forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];   
     //[addressDict setObject:@"0568" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];  
     //[addressDict setObject:@"Oslo" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey]; 
       ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(address, addressDict, kABWorkLabel, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty, address, &error); 
      [addressDict release];
      CFRelease(address); 
      // End of Address
}
              if (error != NULL) 
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    [(id)person autorelease];
    return person;
}


  - (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonView          didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{}
```

I have done like that in this example that I can add a new contact with my information but I can not for example add information for existing contacts

Comment: Did you go through this SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821239/adding-phone-number-to-iphone-contact-but-not-replacing. It will give you an idea. Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739417/adding-a-new-number-to-existing-abrecord-in-abaddressbook-iphone See if [this](http://mrrask.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/add-entry-to-contacts-using-iphone-sdk/) helps